# Isomorphism Classes

Tags: group-theory, matrices

I'm trying to find what the isomorphism class of the group of $G = n\times n$ matrices with $\pm 1$ along the diagonal and zeroes everywhere else.

My approach was first to show that because for each entry of the diagonal we have $2$ choices, there are $2^n$ distinct elements in the group. Furthermore, $\forall A \in G$, $A^2 = I$, therefore every element has order two. Therefore, $G$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{2}\oplus \mathbb Z_{2}\oplus \mathbb Z_{2}\oplus\dotsb\oplus \mathbb Z_{2}$, where there are $n$ copies of $\mathbb Z_{2}$.

Is this correct? 
And if it is, is there a better notation for "$\mathbb Z_{2}\oplus \mathbb Z_{2}\oplus \mathbb Z_{2}\oplus \dotsb\oplus \mathbb Z_{2}$, where there are $n$ copies of $\mathbb Z_{2}$"?

Comment: The argument is completely correct. An alternative notation is $(Z_2)^n$.

Comment: Alright cool thanks!